# DispatchGroup notify before all leave called

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I have an iOS application that runs multiple classes(every class in a separate thread) and I want to get a notification when all the class finishes their run.

So I have a BaseClass:

```
class BaseClass {
    var completeState: CompleteState
    
    init(completeState: CompleteState) {
        self.completeState = completeState
        self.completeState.dispatch.enter()
    }
    
    func start() { }
}
```

And this is the CompleteState Class:

```
class CompleteState {
    let userId:String
    let dispatch = DispatchGroup()
    
    init(userId:String) {
        self.userId = userId
        dispatch.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
            print("Finish load all data")
        }
    }
}
```

And I have multiple classes that inherit from `BaseClass`, and all of them are in this form:

```
class ExampleClass1: BaseClass {
    override func start() {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            print("ExampleClass1 - Start running")

            //DOING SOME CALCULATIONS
            
            print("ExampleClass1 - Finish running")
            self.completeState.dispatch.leave()
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code that runs all of this:

```
public class RunAll {
    let completeState: CompleteState
    let classArray: [BaseClass]
    
    public init(userId: String) {
        self.completeState = CompleteState(userId: userId)
        classArray = [ExampleClass1(completeState: completeState),
                          ExampleClass2(completeState: completeState),
                          ExampleClass3(completeState: completeState),
                          ExampleClass4(completeState: completeState),
                          ExampleClass5(completeState: completeState),
                          ExampleClass6(completeState: completeState),
                          ExampleClass7(completeState: completeState),
                          ExampleClass8(completeState: completeState),
                          ExampleClass9(completeState: completeState)]

        startClasses()
    }
    
    private func startClasses() {
        for foo in classArray {
            foo.start()
        }
    }
}
```

And the problem is that I get `dispatch.notify` called before all the classes finish their work, any idea what is the problem?

Comment: You must call `enter` at least once **before** the `notify` line is reached. Consider to use Swift Concurrency.

Comment: You are not using DispatchGroup correctly. You should have _one_ group for several async operations, then call `enter()` when you start one, and `leave()` when an operation finishes. You use `notify()` to get informed, when the internal operation "counter" reaches zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup/2016066-notify) for `notify` states:

> This function schedules a notification block to be submitted to the specified queue when all blocks associated with the dispatch group have completed. If the group is empty (no block objects are associated with the dispatch group), the notification block object is submitted immediately. When the notification block is submitted, the group is empty.

You are calling `dispatch.notify()` in your `CompleteState` `init`.  At the time you are calling `notify`, the dispatch group is empty, because you haven't yet created a `BaseClass` subclass let along called `start`, which is where the dispatch group is entered.

Because you call `notify` when the dispatch group is empty, the block is submitted immediately.

It may be worth looking into `OperationQueue`, but if you want to use what you have you can split the `notify` out from the `init`:

```
lass CompleteState {
    let userId:String
    let dispatch = DispatchGroup()
    
    init(userId:String) {
        self.userId = userId
    }
    
    func registerCompletionBlock(handler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.dispatch.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: handler)
    }
}
```

You would then provide the completion block after you call `startClasses`

```
public init(userId: String) {
        self.completeState = CompleteState(userId: userId)
        classArray = [ExampleClass1(completeState: completeState),
                          ExampleClass2(completeState: completeState),
                          ExampleClass3(completeState: completeState),
                          ExampleClass4(completeState: completeState),
                          ExampleClass5(completeState: completeState),
                          ExampleClass6(completeState: completeState),
                          ExampleClass7(completeState: completeState),
                          ExampleClass8(completeState: completeState),
                          ExampleClass9(completeState: completeState)]

        startClasses()
        self.completeState.registerCompletionBlockHandler {
            print("Finish load all data")
        }
    }
```